# name of sheet in vba if sheet names are in two words

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, spreadsheet

In my excel vba code I need to refer to two sheets called "Programming plan" and "Compare Files"

I will use the following statement:

```
Sheet17.Cells(i, 12).Formula = "=IF((ISERROR(MATCH(programmingplan!l" & i & ",CompareFiles!H:H,0))),ProgrammingPlan!l" & i & ","""")"
```

My problem is how to write "programming plan" and "compare files" in the vba statement, like:

```
Sheet17.Cells(i, 12).Formula = "=IF((ISERROR(MATCH(programming plan!l" & i & ",Compare Files!H:H,0))),Programming Plan!l" & i & ","""")"
```

I have tried to write [programming plan] and the like, but it did not help.

The code runs well if I change the names of the sheets to "programmingplan" and "comparefiles". But the user wants the sheet names to be kept in two words.

Comment: When dealing with formulas in VBA and unsure what exactly to write: Enter the formula in a cell, stay in that cell, go to the VBA editor, open the immediate window and type `? activecell.formula`.

Answer (score 2):

You need to include the sheet names in single quotes (`'`) when there is a space in them:

```
 "=IF((ISERROR(MATCH('programming plan'!l" & i & ",'Compare Files'!H:H,0))),'Programming Plan'!l" & i & ","""")"
```